How to use ES export with browserify as main entry point?
I need to create a UMD file so I can use Firebase on CodePen without an ES Module, I know that ES Modules are good support, but I want to use CodePen scripts.
I have this code:
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/database';

export default firebase;

and I use this command to generate the bundle:
npx browserify firebase.js -o js/firebase.js -s firebase -p esmify

But this creates a variable firebase that looks like this:
{default: {…}, __esModule: true}
default
: 
{__esModule: true, initializeApp: ƒ, app: ƒ, registerVersion: ƒ, setLogLevel: ƒ, …

If I use
export { firebase };

I got this as a result in the browser:
{__esModule: true}

How to properly export the firebase  object in the ES Module so I can call:
firebase.initializeApp(config);

in the browser, just like a normal Firebase with ES Module.
NOTE: I'm not tagging firebase since this is an issue with the ES Modules and Browserify, and it's not related to using Firebase.

Browserify hasn't had a release in 4 years. Time to update your tooling maybe?

@Evert Do you know any alternative?

search keyword is 'bundler'.
